# The application failed to start for UI Test

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, microsoft-test-manager

I have a UIcoded test that works in VS2010.

I want automated it with MTM. But when I associated it with test case and run it I get this error in ViewResult :

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException: The application failed to start.

I am monitoring it in test agent status and every thing is ok.

how I can pass this test.

Sincerely you M.Bagheri

Answer (score 2):

If you are running UI Coded test in the build process using TFS Build Service, make sure you run the build service as an interactive process.

The answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/cfd6a92e-c0c1-4bd7-a2aa-f2db1f3e7503) also tells you how to make the interactive build service start when the build machine is started.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx) for how to run the build service as an interactive process.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will get a specific error if you cannot interact with the desktop.

I recently received this error. I performed the following tasks which solved the issue for me:

1. clear the controler temporary files
2. restart the agent and controller.